# Python - Searching text with NLTK

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following text file (You can download it from, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lztwlvo9myexd36/NLTK.txt?dl=1)).

I'm trying to search the file for the word `language`. For that, I have the following Python script:

```
import nltk

file = open('NLTK.txt', 'r')
read_file = file.read()
text = nltk.Text(read_file)
match = text.concordance('language')
print(match)
```

When I run the program however, I get the following output although the file contains the word `language`:

```
No matches
None
```

Why couldn't the program find the word `language` althou it exists in the file?

**EDIT 1**

I noticed that the statement `text = nltk.Text(read_file)` returns:

```
<Text: T h i s   i s  ...>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct about how to solve the problem, but here's another piece of advice: Don't bother learning to work with the `Text` class; it is designed for interactive exploration and demonstrations only. Go straight to `PlaintextCorpusReader` (and its counterparts for annotated formats).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you need to tokenize first to handle raw text ([as per ch3](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch03.html)). Tokenizing and then processing gave me results in your example text.

```
import nltk

file = open('NLTK.txt', 'r')
read_file = file.read()
text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(read_file))

match = text.concordance('language')
```

Or alternatively, you can use nltk corpus reader to do the tokenizing and processing like this;

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader

corp = PlaintextCorpusReader(r'C:/', 'NLTK.txt')
text = nltk.Text(corp.words())

match = text.concordance('language')
```

match results;

```
Displaying 18 of 18 matches:
                                   Language Processing . By `` natural languag
                                   language '' we mean a language that is used
                                   language that is used for everyday communic
licit rules . We will take Natural Language Processing ・or NLP for short ・in a
f computer manipulation of natural language . At one extreme , it could be as
ted access to stored information , language processing has come to play a cent
e textbook for a course on natural language processing or computational lingui
is based on the Python programming language together with an open source libra
 source library called the Natural Language Toolkit ( NLTK ) . NLTK includes e
s are deployed in a variety of new language technologies . For this reason it
rite programs that analyze written language , regardless of previous programmi
is book to get immersed in natural language processing . All relevant Python f
ty for this application area . The language index will help you locate relevan
mples and dig into the interesting language analysis material that starts in 1
 text using Python and the Natural Language Toolkit . To learn about advanced
an help you manipulate and analyze language data , and how to write these prog
s are used to describe and analyse language How data structures and algorithms
and algorithms are used in NLP How language data is stored in standard formats
```

Comment: which one's faster out of 2 ?